# Display a year from calendar in ExtJS 4

Tags: extjs4

I'm using a calendar in ExtJS 4, and I want my field to display only a year.

Currently, when I use a calendar it displays in my field this kind of date: "08/20/2013".

I'm using this code:

```
{
    xtype: 'datefield',
    fieldLabel: 'test',
    id: 'yearOfExecution',
    dateFormat: 'd/m/y',
    anchor:'20%',
    displayField: 'label',
    valueField: 'value'
}
```

As I said, I only want to display a year (from my previous example, it should display "2013").

Should I modify this line?

```
displayField: 'label'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing date format to 'y'. This should be in the (thorough) Sencha API.